# XML Reading - node access

Tags: c#, xml

```
<node label="Chemist Name">
    <node label="John,Smith" searchId="1122" />
</node>
```

Hi,

if i have the above as part of my xml structure, and i want to find a tag where the parent has a label of "Chemist Name" and its inner tag has a label of John,Smith so i can then get the searchid - what would be the best way of doing it?

is there a way where i can, rather than unefficiently looping through every xml value in my document just directly say

"get me the node where its parent is chemist name and its child has a label of john smith"

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XPath with the following query:

```
//node[@label = "Chemist Name"]/node[@label = "John,Smith"]
```

You can use it like this in C#:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(
        @"//node[@label = ""Chemist Name""]/node[@label = ""John,Smith""]");
```

Where `xml` is a string containing the XML data. If you want to load the XML directly from disc, use [`XmlDocument.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx) instead.

Comment: where node is the xml document?

Comment: great thanks for that - i guess this is a handy tool i need to learn. would you say its more efficinet or does this kind of approach have an overhead too?

Comment: @ricki: If your XML document is huge, this is not the best way to do it, because `XmlDocument` first reads the whole file and then applies the XPath query. If you have a huge XML document, a SAX parser like `XmlReader` would be more suitable. But in general, XPath is the way to go, if you want to find a node, that's what it was invented for.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - i have replaced the names with parameters and i get an invalid token exception, i cant really see what i have done wrong - "'//node[@label = Chemist Name]/node[@label = John,Smith]' has an invalid token."

Comment: @ricki: The attribute values (Chemist Name and John, Smith) need to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

xpath is the way to go with this. you should read more on the [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x3f76ta.aspx), and [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp). If you're stuck, post back and we can help out.